# Psql Numeric type for price

Tags: psql

I created a migration in Sequel:

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    create_table(:products) do
      primary_key :id
      String :name, :null=>false
      Numeric :price, :null=>false
      Text :description, :null=>false
    end
  end

  down do
    drop_table(:products)
  end
end
```

I used Numeric type for price, and now when I put "5" in form, it returns from my database as 0.5E1. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

this is scientific notation.

`0.5E1` means exactly `5`

I assume it is not database settings to keep number in such format, but rather client to show so. So in your quoted code nothing is wrong.